# How to check a Favorite button, if it is clicked before? Selenium-Webdriver

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Imagine you have a button , to favor some jobs or list elements. That button because Dark and light changes color depending on if it was clicked before.

Here is my button;

```
<button class="button button--noshadow button--square job-favorite-button-for-job-2022" onclick="scv.ui.actions.jobs.addFavorite(2022);return false;" data-scv-action-key="favorite" data-scv-action-value="2022">
```

Thing is If i can check `"data-scv-action-key="favorite"` if it is = favorite or unfavorite, My problem will be solved. Just wanna know how can I check `"data-scv-action-key= ?"` by Using Selenium WebDriver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//To click on button

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@classs,'job-favorite-button-for-job-2022')]").click();

//To get the key value

    String actionKey=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@classs,'job-favorite-button-for-job-2022')]")).getAttribute("data-scv-action-key");

//To check the value

    if(actionKey.equals("unfavorite"){
        System.out.println("The button is clicked");
    }
    else{
       System.out.println("The button is clicked");
    }
```

Comment: getAttribute is Undefined for the type By , when I use your //To get the key value part.

Comment: Sorry for my stupidity. Your code was missing a parenthesis. Thanks for your help. It worked.